# Сколько используется ресурсов процессора согласно выводу программы top?

Tags: linux, top

Сервер работает на дистрибутиве debian gnu/linux 7. Запускаю конвертацию видеофайла через ffmpeg размером 400мб из формата avi в mp4. Команда простейшая, без дополнительных параметров:

```
$ ffmpeg -i pathInput -f mp4 pathOutput
```

Решил посмотреть использование ресурсов сервера командой top.
Вот какую информацию получил по процессу ffmpeg

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
55291 admin     20   0  379m 120m 5484 S 378.5  0.2  17:08.12 ffmpeg
```

Если не ошибаюсь, согласно этим данным, используется 378.5% CPU.

Как это может быть? Я неправильно интерпретирую эти значения?

Comment: У вас небось 4 ядра?

Comment: (А так вообще оффтопик. Сколько конкретно ресурсов использует, зависит от мощности процессора.)

Comment: Да у процессора 4 ядра, и если я правильно посмотрел, частота 3.1Ггц. Значит этот процент формируется в результате сложения нагрузки на каждое ядро?

Comment: Угу, именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

число в столбце `%cpu` (процент использоания процессора) суммируется по всем ядрам (реальным или виртуальным) всех процессоров.

в данном случае число `378.5` говорит, скорее всего, о том, что четыре ядра используются почти на сто процентов.

---

кстати, у программы `top` есть возможность показывать (в верхней, «заголовочной» части «окна» программы) не только общую нагрузку на все ядра всех процессоров, но и на каждое ядро в отдельности. переключается этот режим нажатием кнопки <kbd>1</kbd>.

пример вывода по всем ядрам:

```
top - 18:17:10 up 11 days, 13 min, 19 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.25, 0.25
Tasks: 203 total,   1 running, 202 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.9 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.8 id,  1.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8218532 total,  3391900 used,  4826632 free,   468744 buffers
KiB Swap:  2719740 total,        0 used,  2719740 free,  1168472 cached
```

пример вывода по каждому ядру отдельно:

```
top - 18:17:17 up 11 days, 13 min, 19 users,  load average: 0.09, 0.24, 0.25
Tasks: 203 total,   1 running, 202 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  1.6 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.8 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8218532 total,  3409680 used,  4808852 free,   468744 buffers
KiB Swap:  2719740 total,        0 used,  2719740 free,  1190592 cached
```